# The problem of agent switching space for anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I now have an agent named contaienr that has established the following process through the material library:

berth: enter - moveBycrane-exit

main: enter - seizeNearestAGV - moveBycrane -moveByAgv -

My AGV is in the main space, but my carne is in the berth space, so through exit and

enter pairs with each other to switch the agent space, using the setSpace method.

Since the hook is not released during the space switching process, the container screen is always displayed at the origin of main after the switching.

Trying to reset the space using the agent.setXYZ() method also doesn't work.

After trying, if you release the hook at this point, you can synchronize the screen with the setSpace() and setXYZ() methods.

So there must be a problem if the hook isn't released? Is there any way to solve this problem?

I want to get the right solution.

Comment: also play with `setEnvironment(...)`, may be causing this

Comment: Finally, I put all the elements in main to avoid this error. Thank you!